# Change array content from mysql using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, ajax

I have array data that contains some text for the database:

```
{11010110110036| 11010110110065| 11010110110002}
```

and I Have a table

```
nim             nama                        fakultas  
--------------  --------------------------  ----------

11010110110002  RAIEDER ANGGIAT NATANAEL S  HUKUM     
11010110110004  LAILATHUL HADIZA            HUKUM     
11010110110005  MUSRIFAH AF                 HUKUM     
11010110110014  SIBGHOTULLAH QODAFI         HUKUM     
11010110110036  JESSICA CHRISTIANNE         HUKUM     
11010110110057  RISMA HARI WARDANI          HUKUM     
11010110110058  NUR LATIFAH HANUM           HUKUM     
11010110110065  MOH. FIKRI AMRIZAH          HUKUM     
11010110110072  MARIA DITA KRISTIANA        HUKUM     
11010110110085  ANDRISUMA                   HUKUM
```

The process should be something like this:

1. Explode array
2. Change or display nama and fakultas with ajax from array data

[when I use ordinary functions, the browser load is very heavy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG88K.png)

function before

```
function get_mhs($id = null, $mhs){
    $lengthArray = count($mhs);
    $j = 0;
    if($id != null){
      for($i = 0; $i<$lengthArray; $i++){
        if($mhs[$i]->nim == $id){
          $temp[$j] = $mhs[$i];
          $j++;
        }
      }
    }
    return $temp;
  }

public function mhs(){
      $record   = array();
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM data_induk";

      if($results = $this->db->query($sql)){
        if($results->rowCount() > 0){
          while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $record[] = $row;
          }
        }
      }
      return $record;
  }
```

call function

```
<?php
    $temp = array();
    $array = (explode("|", $r->mhs)); $i = count($array);

    for($ii = 0; $ii<$i ; $ii++){
         if($i > 1){
            echo $ii+1 .'. '. $data->get_mhs($array[$ii] , $data->mhs())[0]->nama . "<br>";
         }else{
            echo $data->get_mhs($array[$ii] , $data->mhs())[0]->nama . "<br>";
         }
     }
?>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Show us these 'ordinary functions', so we know what you are trying to do

Comment: this can only be solved if you add the functions which are used, that you are calling `ordinary` .

Comment: @Andys add the code inside your original post via edit link this is not readable here in the comments

Comment: I have entered :)

Comment: what is `$mhs` how is the `function get_mhs($id = null, $mhs)` called and where , what parameter values are passed ?

Comment: mhs is table from database